# How to calculate confidence interval and sample size

Tags: statistics, sampling, confidence-interval

My company has 1000 locations. We will be conducting a survey (lets say to ask "yes" or "no" about something) using a sample of about 250 locations. Based on the results, we hope to estimate the proportion of all companies that is "yes". After surveying 250, say for example the proportion of "yes" is 70% and "no" is 30%. I would like to construct a 95% confidence interval to estimate the proportion of all locations that is "yes".

Question 1 - Do I still use the regular confidence interval calculation for a population proportion, i.e `p_hat +/- z*SQRT((p_hat(1-p_hat)/n)`, or is there another formula since my population "N" in this case is 1000.

Question 2 - Is there a statistical calculation/guidance to determine the correct number of locations to survey in the first place.

Comment: refer this for sample size - [sample_size](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat200/lesson/8/8.1/8.1.1/8.1.1.3)

Comment: and for confidence interval - [refer this](https://openstax.org/books/introductory-business-statistics/pages/8-1-a-confidence-interval-for-a-population-standard-deviation-known-or-large-sample-size)  also based on proportion % and given confidence level, assuming 5% marginal error sample size should be 323.

Comment: @RakeshV Thanks for answering my question. How do you come up with 323. I used a guide for calculating sample size with a finite population and I come up with 278. Please this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gLD4tENS82c

Comment: Yes 278 is correct,i made some calculations error.